# Browser certificate warnings for wilcard domain SSL certificate installed on Amazon ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb

I've setup an Amazon Elastic Load Balancer instance to provide SSL termination to the EC2 instances it balances.

The certificate is a **wildcard domain** variant provided by 123-reg. Verifying the SSL installation using the associated root authority (GlobalSign) using their validation tooling shows 2 issues:

1. **Server configuration does not include all intermediate certificates**
2. **Hostname in certificate and DNS name do not match**

I have been unable to get the ELB instance to accept the certificate chain, and as this is optional have left this out for now. Googling around this issue all I can find is that for browser based consumers of the load balanced resources this is **not infact optional** and will lead to issues. However, I have been unable to find any information about what issues this will cause. Specifically - **is the lack of a certificate chain the reason I am getting the hostname mismatch warning?**

If the lack of a certificate chain is not the reason for the second validation error, does anyone have any idea of what else could be the issue. Some key points are:

1. I have setup the friendly DNS for the load balancer as a CNAME pointing to the DNS shown in the AWS console for the ELB (though it says its actually an A record ...)
2. The instances behind the load balancer are Windows boxes, with the domain names they server added to their respective hosts.ini
3. I have verified the certificate CN is correct and is *.OURDOMAIN.com as required for a wildcard certificate.
4. UPDATE - The domains I am trying to host are actually multi-level subdomains which appears to be the problem.

**NOTE** I am not especially looking for advise on how to upload the certificate chain as this is pretty well covered elsewhere on StackOverflow (although I can't get it to work all the same!). Rather, is the lack of certificate chain the root cause for the hostname/DNS name mismatch, which is what I have been unable to fathom.

Comment: The certificate chain isn't optional in the sense that you're thinking.  It's optional in the sense that ELB doesn't require it, since not every cert may need it.  It sounds like yours does.  Also, at the risk of asking the obvious, does the hostname pointed at the ELB match "something".yourdomain.com?  With no dots in the "something" part?

Comment: Wildcard certs are not valid for multi-level subdomains.. eg. if you have something like sub.domain.example.com, and your cert is for *.example.com, it will throw this error.

Comment: Ah ha! All the load balancers I have setup are actually being used for multi-level subdomains - so thats the problem then. I had no idea that there was any technical difference. May be worth you putting your comment into an answer for future reference?